# Check whether a column value exist in another column values starting from second position sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing to check if the first row value of a particular column is equal to the second row value of another column.

Example:

[image]

In the above example, for order S1, I am looking for first product key '2' to be checked with ParentProductKey from second line.

If it matches then 'YES' else 'NO'.

Also if the product key matches for 2,3 and 4 (in general the rest), then the first row should also be 'YES'.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: second row as in parent product column row 2

Comment: just do a simple `WHERE EXISTS( . . .)` condition

Comment: Your example is a bit misleading. For the rows with ProductKey 3,4 and 5 they have 'YES' but shouldn't they have 'NO' ? (if we assume that there are no entries with ParentProductKey 3,4,5 in the table)

Answer (score 0):

You might use syntax that looks likes this:

```
WITH CTE AS  -- end previous statement with semi colon.
(
    SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN C2.SomeColumn = C.SomeColumn THE AS ELSE B END AS Comparison
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumb
)

SELECT C.*, 
FROM CTE AS C
LEFT JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C.RowNumb = C2.RowNumb - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want to see whether or not the rows ProductKey exist in the ParentProduct column of the table this query will work. It will simply do an exist check to see if it does exist but it will not take Order into consideration. If you want to check that there is one/many rows that has a ProductKey that match one/many rows in the ParentProduct column for that specific order, add a join on Order in the subquery.

```
 SELECT *, 
 case 
    when EXISTS(Select 1 from ORDERS t2 where t2.ParentProductKey = t1.ProductKey) then 'YES' else 'NO' end as Result
 FROM ORDERS t1
```

Comment: Hi Holder, a small modification. The query should say yes also for the first row of parent product. but only first row.

Comment: @Shivang Please edit your question with the new information and add some expected results.

Comment: @Shivang I might not be understanding you correctly but I believe my query is doing what you are saying.

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @LuFFy Thanks for the comment. I added an explanation to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You seems want `APPLY` :

```
SELECT t.*, (CASE WHEN t.ProductKey = t1.ParentProductKey THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS Result
FROM table t OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT TOP (1) t1.*
       FROM table t1
       WHERE t1.sid = t.sid and t1.ProductKey > t.ProductKety
       ORDER BY t1.ProductKey 
     ) t1;
```